# Read Russian text from the console [dart]

Tags: flutter, dart

How can Russian text be read from the console?
I tried like this

```dart
var answer = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')!)!;
```

and like this

```dart
stdin.transform(utf8.decoder)
```

but if you try to print a string using print, then nothing will be output.

Additional:

```dart
answer.codeUnits.forEach(print);
// output
// 0
// 0
// 0
// 0
```

I enter simple words:

- привет
- нет
- да

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, I have a problem with all windows terminals, even if I put internal git bash in vs code, then nothing will work, it will only work if I open external git bash.

The most incomprehensible and surprising thing is that all terminals work in UTF-8 mode (65001), but only git bash work reads Russian characters.

In the Dart itself, I also tried to change the code table, more details in the [github issues #47133](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47133)